# How to list all help subjects and help files?

Tags: help-system

**Q1:** How can I list all vim help subjects (topics)?
i.e., the `{subject}` argument for `:h[elp] {subject}`

**Q2:** How can I list all vim help files?

My particular use case is that I want to see help for my various vim plugins, and I don't know what the subject is for a given plugin.

I tried `:help`  followed by CTRL-D for commandline completion, but it doesn't show me all the subjects
(e.g., it's not showing me `table-mode` which is present when I do `:help table-mode`):

```
:help
help                               :helptags                          gzip-helpfile
:help                              'helpfile'                         online-help
--help                             'helplang'                         add-local-help
:helpc                             :helpclose                         ale-vim-help-options
:helpf                             'helpheight'                       ale-vim-help-write-good
:helpg                             help-context                       write-local-help
:helpt                             help-summary                       <Help>
t_help                             help-writing                       youcompleteme-help-advice-support
help.txt                           helphelp.txt                       i_<Help>
helphelp                           help-translated                    g:ycm_disable_signature_help
help-tags                          help-xterm-window                  youcompleteme-signature-help
:helpfind                          helpfile_name.txt                  :lhelpgrep
:helpgrep                          netrw-help                         netrw-quickhelp
```

Comment: There are **a lot** of help tags. A quick `:vimgrep "\*.\+\*" $VIMRUNTIME/docs/*.txt` to search for tags in the help files returned 7191 results. You might be better off using `:h :helpgrep` for whatever plugin you're trying to search for.

Comment: Try `:helptags ALL` and then `:help`; local plugins help should be displayed somewhere on that page under the heading « local additions » or similar

Comment: That's why it is best practice to add a particular help tag for the plugin you are actually using. So I can always do `:h pluginname` and then search in there. I do that with all my plugins and I think most other plugins I use also do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A1.a:**  To get a list of all help topics (of which there can be thousands), you can define and call the following function to read all help-tags files into a new buffer:

```
function! ListHelpSubjects()
    new
    for f in globpath(&runtimepath, '**/doc/tags', 0, 1)
        call append('$', readfile(f))
    endfor
endfunction
```

which can be put in your `.vimrc` and called from the command line:

`:call ListHelpSubjects()`

This gives you a list of all help topics that are known to Vim. Every line contains *one* help topic, the file where it is defined (which often, but not always hints at the corresponding plugin), and the search pattern that is used for locating the topic in the help file.

---

**A1.b:** The following commands are a little bit more complex, but they prefix the names of the help files with their actual directories so that you can put the cursor on them and press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the help file in another buffer:

```
function LoadHelpTags(filename)
    let docpath = substitute(a:filename, '\\', '/', 'g')
    let docpath = substitute(docpath, '/tags$', '/', '')

    let tags = readfile(a:filename)

    return map(tags, { idx, val -> substitute(val, '\t', '\t' . docpath, '') })
endfunction

function! ListHelpFileNames()
    new
    for f in globpath(&runtimepath, '**/doc/tags', 0, 1)
        call append('$', LoadHelpFileNames(f))
    endfor
endfunction
```

As in **A1.a**, these functions can be put in your `.vimrc` and called from the command line:
`:call ListHelpFileNames()`

Actually the last script (**A1.b**) is not really necessary. You can always press <kbd>K</kbd> on the help tags in the list generated by the first example; this will directly open the help file at the correct location.

---

**A2:**
To get the list of help files only one line *needs* to be changed (the changed function name is purely cosmetic):

```
function! LoadHelpFileNames(filename)
    let docpath = substitute(a:filename, '\\', '/', 'g')
    let docpath = substitute(docpath, '/tags$', '/', '')

    let tags = readfile(a:filename)

    return uniq(sort(map(tags, { idx, val -> substitute(val, '.*\t\(.*\)\t.*', docpath . '\1', '') })))
endf

function! ListHelpFileNames()
    new
    for f in globpath(&runtimepath, '**/doc/tags', 0, 1)
        call append('$', LoadHelpFileNames(f))
    endfor
endfunction
```

The `return` line now removes everything before and including the first tab and everything after and including the second tab. The remaining file name is again prefixed with the corresponding directory. The list of file names is then sorted and made unique.

Comment: That gives me exactly what I asked for ⭐️ , which then leads me to the question: 
How can I list all help filenames (a list of distinct filenames)? 
(i.e., all the files associated with all the topics that the first script above outputs)

Comment: @RobBednark See my edited answer.

Comment: Works beautifully!  Thanks @Jürgen!

Comment: @Jürgen_Krämer I just noticed that the script you provided in "A2" lists many of the files twice (I get 402 filenames, and 272 unique filenames).  Not a biggie, I can just `:%!uniq` -- but just curious if the script could easily eliminate duplicates?